# Everything works except Python3 shell

Tags: python-3.x, linux, centos, putty

I am in a CentOS box, via Putty, the term is xterm and I'm using screen.  I can use arrow keys in the command line, in VIM, and in the Python2 interpreter, but when I try to use arrow keys in the Python3 interpreter (we have both Python2.7 and Python3.6.3 installed on this particular machine) I see escape keys.  Any suggestions?

I've found another article here in stackoverflow and they said to install readline, and I have, but this did not fix it.  The issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED.  Arrow keys worked in Python2, in Python3.x I needed to do tis.

Ran as ROOT on DEV "yum install readline-devel"
And then ran (because pip3 is missing) "python3 -m pip install gnureadline"